# SBT gives "class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 49.0" when compiling a mixed project?

Tags: scala, sbt, javac

EDIT: Various SBT options

```
show scalacOptions
List(-deprecation, -unchecked, -encoding, UTF-8, -Yinline-warnings, -feature)

show javaOptions
List()

about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/ThomasNorth/Documents/CODE/SERVER/MonetiseAlpha/monetise-webserver/}monetise-webserver 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info]
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

I am getting the following error when attempting to compile a scala project with some java sources, the error is as follows

```
[error] /Users/ThomasNorth/Documents/CODE/SERVER/MonetiseAlpha/monetise-webserver/src/main/java/com/boxbe/pub/email/EmailAddress.java:31: cannot access java.util.regex.Pattern
[error] bad class file: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/regex/Pattern.class)
[error] class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 49.0
[error] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[error] import java.util.regex.Pattern;
[error]                        ^
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed 28/02/2014 3:36:38 PM
```

The thing is, both javac and java are updated to their latest versions

javac -version

```
javac 1.7.0_51
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
```

java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

build.sbt

organization  := "com.monetise"

name := "webserver"

version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("release"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
  "Untyped" at "http://ivy.untyped.com/com.untyped/"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-unchecked",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-Yinline-warnings",
  "-feature"
  // "-Xcheckinit" // for debugging only, see https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki/Initialization-Order
  // "-optimise"   // this option will slow your build
)
```

And I only have a single sdk installed, which is located at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home`

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

I have even attempted to put this in my globals.sbt

```
javaHome := Some(file("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home"))
```

To force the java home. SBT is v 0.13.1

System is Mac Osx 10.9.2 (Mavericks)

Comment: "class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 49.0" this means you're using `javac` from JDK 5, while using the class libraries from JDK 7. Make sure `JAVA_HOME` points to your JDK 7 installation directory.

Comment: Tried: " export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` " in terminal, to specify JAVA_HOME, but still got the same error.

Comment: How does your build configuration files look like - `build.sbt` or `project/*.scala` files? Do you use any? Could you run `show scalacOptions` and `show javaOptions` and `about` in SBT console and add the outputs to the question?

Comment: Check the edit, various options

Comment: How are you launching sbt? If it's a script, can you post its contents?

Comment: I have seen this result when build.sbt specifies unmanagedClasspath entries (e.g., jars in a ./lib directory) if the jars were compiled with a newer version of javac.

Comment: Well, since 1.7 is the only JDK you have and Pattern is part of it, the 49.0 probably comes from something you compiled; how about you check (and specifically set) -source / -target compiler options to use 1.7 for compliance. Especially -target needs to be 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `javaHome` setting to specify the version of java used to *launch* sbt, that will only specify which JDK sbt will look in, and which binaries it will use when it forks.  Unfortunately, the startup scripts for sbt dont' know how to look at this `javaHome` setting and update themselves.

What `sbt` script are you using?  Can you add a `which sbt` output, and show us the contents of this script?  Most likely *this* file is pulling the MacOSX native JDK and not the one you've installed.